# permissions for installing packages on julia in slurm cluster

Tags: julia, slurm

I've just installed julia for usage on a slurm cluster.  Running a hello world job works well, so the installation was successful ... until installing a first package which gives some permissions issues.  Script with command

```
Pkg.add("MAT")
```

or

```
Pkg.installed()
```

gives error message

```
ERROR: LoadError: SystemError (with /home/<my_user_name>/.julia/logs): mkdir: Permission denied
```

The same error appears if I start up julia command line from the user directory.  Such message disappears when starting julia using sudo, but obviously cannot sudo cluster jobs.

I tried installing the pkg with sudo on the user account, then just using it non-sudo, but other error messages arise similar to those documented here.
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12876
On this page it's indicated to chown user MAT.ji , but that does not work.  I tried removing and re-add the package but I'm just running in circles with the same error messages.  I also got, at one point, error messages like EACCES similar to documented here
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/juliapro-pkg-installation-error-ioerror-unlink-permission-denied-eacces/35912

I'm a novice with permissions issues like this, so I could use some guidance on how to approach this problem.  I'm not sure what to try, and in what order.

Comment: Looks vaguely like `/home/user/.julia` belongs to the wrong user; it should be owned by the `julia` user. (The dot at the start looks peculiar, out perhaps there is a reason for that.) How did you create this user and the directory?

Comment: @triplee In the Julian world the path `/home/user/.julia`  looks perfectly fine to me. @dj_a what user account you use to launch the julia process? how do you initiate the installation? One typical problem might be that you have spawned several install processes at the same node and they have blocked each other.

Comment: the installation of julia itself was done with sudo privileges in the apps folder as per instructions like so using wget https://cloud.google.com/architecture/installing-apps-slurm-clusters-compute-engine  .  I don't know exactly how to interpret "several install processes at the same node", sorry, am muddling my way through this.

Comment: the julia process is being launched by submitting a job through the cluster using sbatch, from the user account

Comment: It's best to install the Julia binary in your home directory without using `sudo`.

Comment: I tried this just now.  I installed julia in the user home directory.  It runs but upon opening gives error ERROR: SystemError (with /home/user/.julia/logs): mkdir: Permission denied

Comment: To clarify, is the path mentioned in the SystemError actually `/home/user/<your_user_name>/.julia/logs`? Because if the path is actually `/home/user/.julia/logs`, then it looks like you might not have installed it in your home directory.

Comment: You basically should install with the same user that you use later with `sbatch` - this would be the easiest and safest way. I would actually consider going with `srun` with running my Julia installation (strongly depends on your environment though)

Comment: the path I mentioned is /home/<my_user_name>/.julia/logs  and yes, I am running sbatch from the same user account with <my_user_name>

Comment: I don't think I want to use srun, because I don't need jobs generally to be interactive.   I need to resolve the permissions issue in the OP while using sbatch.

Comment: It sounds like resolving your issue will involve some investigation. You might be able to get more advice on https://discourse.julialang.org/

Answer (score 1):

Permissions issues on clusters can be tricky.

If we are talking about a physical cluster, the simplest generic solution that you can probably get to work without involving your sysadmin is probably to just install your `.julia` somewhere where just about every process has filesystem permissions. Namely, global networked scratch (wherever that exactly is on your cluster).

This is arguably a good idea anyways, given that global scratch tends to be the fastest or one of the fastest networked filesystems around on most clusters, and *every* julia process is going to have to read from `.julia` when you start a job, so if that's on a fast parallel filesystem, so much the better. On the other hand, scratch tends to have a time limit, so you might want to keep a local copy around for when `scratch/<yourusername>/.julia` inevitably gets deleted.

In order for this to work well, you have tell Julia so that it knows where to look for `.julia`, and not to just make a new one when it doesn't find it in the default location (`~`). One relatively simple way to do this is with environment variables. You could do this manually, but I recommend instead putting something like the following in your `~/.bash_profile`.

```
# Some julia-specific environment variables
# To make sure I call the Julia installation in global scratch
export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH="/path/to/your/global/scratch/username/.julia"
export JULIA_PROJECT="/path/to/your/global/scratch/username/.julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml"
export JULIA_LOAD_PATH="/path/to/your/global/scratch/username/.julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml:/path/to/your/julia/application/folder/possibly/also/in/scratch/julia-1.6.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6" # The second one may be tricky to find if you're using a cluster-provided julia, but you can always just download the latest julia release yourself and plop it in scratch too
export JULIA_BINDIR="/path/to/your/julia/application/folder/possibly/also/in/scratch/julia-1.6.1/bin" # This last line may not be necessary, but doesn't hurt to specify.
```

where julia versions and the actual path to your global scratch folder are adjusted as appropriate.