# Change where Julia is storing /logs/manifest_usage.toml

Tags: docker, julia

I'm getting this error when I run Julia in Docker:

```
julia.core.JuliaError: Exception 'SystemError: opening file "/root/.julia/logs/manifest_usage.toml": Read-only file system' occurred while calling julia code:
```

I tried setting [JULIA_HISTORY](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_HISTORY), but that doesn't seem to be respected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you actually probably want to move your whole `.julia` folder, assuming that the whole `/root/` directory is probably going to give you filesystem permission errors unless you always run as root within your docker image.

You can control the location of the `.julia` directory at first install with the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` environment variable, which is described in a bit more detail in this answer: [permissions for installing packages on julia in slurm cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67794194/permissions-for-installing-packages-on-julia-in-slurm-cluster?answertab=active#tab-top), though depending on how you are installing Julia, you may be able to more easily sidestep the whole issue by just not using `sudo` when installing Julia.